# plot: straight regression line and prediction bands

Tags: prediction

I have realized a multiple linear regression. 
To know how well my model does in terms of prediction, I can compute prediction intervals bands and decide if they are narrow enough to be of use. If they are too wide, then they probably are not useful.

Using R, I have written these R codes.

```
LinearModel.1 <- lm(GDP.per.head ~ Competitivness.score + Quality.score, 
                    data=Dataset)
summary(LinearModel.1)
predict(LinearModel.1, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf, 
        interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), level = 0.95, 
        type = c("response", "terms"), terms = NULL)
```

Here is an example code:

```
 # generate random numbers for the domain
 x = rnorm(10)
 y = rnorm(10)

 # make up some sample data to be fit.
 z = 3*x+2*y - 5 + rnorm(10,sd=3.5)

 # Perform the regression
 fit = lm(z~x+y)

 # Find some points to use to plot the confidence interval
 # and then use the predict command to get the bounds on
 # the confidence interval
 x1 = (-20:20)/10
 y1 = (-20:20)/10
 p = predict(fit,data.frame(x=x1,y=y1),interval='confidence')

 # Now plot the original points, then plot the predicted values and the
 # upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval.
 plot(x,z)
 points(x1,p[,1],col=2,type='l')
 points(x1,p[,2],col=3,type='l')
 points(x1,p[,3],col=4,type='l')
```

I try to do the same with my LinearModel.1. I mean I would like to plot the original points, then plot the predicted values and the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval. I don't get the R code to do that with my LinearModel.1. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Questions about 'how to do this in R' are off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topoc)), but can be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). However, this question would need to be closed on SO as well, because (1) it is not clear what you are asking about, & (2) there is no [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/). Can you edit this to clarify what help you need w/ your code, & add some example data that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I know that I can use the "predict" command in R to generate the prediction interval for a set of points. My general idea (what I try to do) is to find the linear regression using the lm command. Then I use the predict command to get the prediction interval for a set of points in the domain. Then plot out the predicted values as well as the upper and lower limits of the prediction intervals for those values.

Comment: Is there a question in there? What do you need help with?

Comment: Here is an example code:

x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)

z = 3*x+2*y - 5 + rnorm(10,sd=3.5)

fit = lm(z~x+y)

x1 = (-20:20)/10
y1 = (-20:20)/10
p = predict(fit,data.frame(x=x1,y=y1),interval='confidence')

plot(x,z)
points(x1,p[,1],col=2,type='l')
points(x1,p[,2],col=3,type='l')
points(x1,p[,3],col=4,type='l') I try to do the same with my LinearModel.1 <- lm(GDP.per.head ~ Competitivness.score + Quality.score, data=Dataset)

Comment: Please don't put these things in comments. Edit your Q to add the relevant information. I still don't see any question. What do you need help with?